# Type 'ObjectId' is not assignable to type 'Expression' in mongodb aggregate

Tags: typescript, mongodb

guys when i want to aggregate in mongoDB using typescript i got this error

```
Type 'ObjectId' is not assignable to type 'Expression'
```

for this section

```
user_id: new ObjectId("62aed7171b22341ad759d6f1")
```

this is my code for where I want to make an aggregate with my schema

```
await u.aggregate([
{
  $match: {
    // my error is here
    user_id: new ObjectId("62aed7171b22341ad759d6f1")
  }
},
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "tools.new_event_alert.new_support_alert.conditions.appearance_settings",
    localField: "_id",
    foreignField: "condition_id",
    as: "3"
  },
}
 ], {}, (e, r) => {
console.log(e)
console.log(r)
 })
```

and this is my schema

```
export default model("tools.new_event_alert.new_support_alert.conditions", new Schema<IToolsNewDonationConditions>({
user_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
type_of_conditions: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: conditions_enums,
    default: conditions_enums.amount_of_support_greater_than_or_equal_to_an_amount
},
amount: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    unique: true
}
 }, {
     timestamps: true,
 }))
```

and this is my interface

```
export interface IToolsNewDonationConditions {
_id: ObjectId;
user_id: ObjectId
type_of_conditions: String
amount: Number
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can use:

```
$match: { $expr : { $eq: [ '$_id' , { $toObjectId: "62aed7171b22341ad759d6f1" } ] } }
```

Found in [this site.](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/aggregate-match-id-eq-toobjectid-not-working/145965/4)